# Saving Listview Item State

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview in my app that contains 50 movies. When a user clicks on a movie in the listview, the alpha changes from 1f to 0.2f. I would like to set it so that when I exit the activity and the app itself, the items in the listview that have been clicked will remain at 0.2f when it is reopened, so that the user knows which movies on the list they have watched. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, topMovies);

    moviesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.pindrop);
moviesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (view.getAlpha() == 1f) {

                mPlayer.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Watched " + topMovies.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                view.animate().alpha(0.2f);
            } else {

                view.animate().alpha(1f);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where do the movies come from, i.e. what adapter are you using? The state should be saved by the adapter items (think model-view). Android gives you a number of choices including a full scale SQL backend.

Comment: Sorry, I've added in the extra code now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do something a little bit different. 
Create a selector in your drawable folder
selector.xml

drawable_selected.xml

```
    <shape>
<solid color="enter your color here"/>
</shape>
```

drawable_unselected.xml

```
<shape>
<solid color="enter your color here" />
</shape>
```

selector.xml

```
 <selector>
    <item android:stateSelected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_selected"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_unselected"/>
 </selector>
```

then define your view background

```
view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector);
```

and then when you select your view

```
view.setSelected(true);
```

it'll automatically change your background. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. When I created the selector file and pasted that code in the @drawable/drawable_selected and unselected are both red. Also should I define the view background and select the view inside the onCreate method? I'm new to this so sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: You should define your own drawable_selected and drawable_unselected. I'll update my answer.

Comment: you should set your view as selected when the view is clicked I suppose :)

Comment: Thanks I added those three xml files in drawable. The two item tags in the selector.xml have red exclamation marks to their left and when I tried to define the view, getDrawable has a black line running through it.

Comment: It means that this method is deprecated, but you can still use it. About the red lines, please verify if your files are named correctly

Comment: I created them by right clicking drawable and selecting new->drawable resource file so maybe I did that wrong. This is the selector.xml file:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:stateSelected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_selected"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_unselected"/>
</selector>

Comment: Every single android application has a R file, android studio automatically generates this file for you. Unless you renamed it, it should be there :)

Comment: I am bad enough to do that :) I read that a problem with R is caused by a corrupted XML file so I must have done something wrong with them.

Comment: I got it working now and pasted the two view. lines into the onItemClick method. When I click an item in the listview the colour changes, however when I close the activity it resets to default. Is there any way for it to save it's state when the activity or app is closed?

Comment: If you wanna keep it even when your activity is closed you should have something like isSelected is your object and then consider this isSelected method in your activity onCreate method OR create a sharedPreference file and save what positions are selected (which I wouldn't recommend, because if your item range change then a wrong item would be selected.,